# What happens if I use fishing line in a grass trimmer?

Tags: grass, tools, string-trimmer

Grass trimmer cutting line looks pretty much like very thick fishing line. So it looks like if I find fishing line of exactly the same diameter that is accepted by my grass trimmer head it should be okay. Meanwhile the grass trimmer manufacturers only recommend specially crafted cutting line.

Is there any difference? What happens if I use fishing line in a grass trimmer?

Comment: Only if you're using something thick enough for deep sea fishing rather large fish. Fish line is a pretty poor substitute for the most part.

Comment: You don't mention where you are, but the hardware stores in AZ sell "generic" string trimmer line that is pretty inexpensive. Try a "farm store" if you have such a thing in your area. If you were able to find fishing line with the same diameter, I'd think it would be significantly more expensive than string trimmer line. I could be completely wrong.  You can also get a string replacement that doesn't use string, but uses articulated durable plastic arms. Never used one, but it's got to be cheaper, right? Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The manual that came with my string trimmer recommended a specific thickness of line.  Then it said if thine was line too thin will have lower aerodynamic drag allowing the motor to spin to fast and overheat the motor.  If the line was to thick the motor would not be able to spin it fast enough to cut.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what happens, but it sounds like an idea I might try.  The only issue I can think is the line may not have enough mass or stiffness to fly-out against the air and have enough mass to slice the plants.

The difference in fishing line and trimmer line is the fishing line is designed to be reeled up on a reel and to be cast off the reel and not remain in coils.  So the fishing line is pliable.  The trimmer line is stiff and doesn't like to be coiled up as much.